# Theorem about Invariant subspace and Mapping Restriction

Tags: invariant-subspace

Can someone provide a proof for the following theorem and explain why **$R$** is exactly the definition of restricting a linear mapping (operator) like $A$**$V$** --> **$V$**, where **$V$** is a finite-dimensional space, in an invariant subspace such as **$S$**; symbolically shown as $A|S$?

Theroem: Consider the mapping **$A$** with the invariant subspace **$S$**. Then, for matrix **$T$**
constructed by the basis of **$S$**, there exists a square matrix **$R$** such that $A T = T R$

Comment: You need to write this better. What is the context here? Hilbert space? Banach space? Finite-dimensional? Infinite-dimensional? You are mixing operators and matrices, and it is not clear why.

Comment: I modified my post.

Comment: The context is finite-dimensional linear spaces, so mapping, operator, matrix are all equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is in a finite-dimensional space $V$, and
$A$ is a linear operator from $V$ into $V$.
Suppose $u_i, i=1\ldots n$ is a basis of the invariant subspace $S$.  So for each $j$ you have $A u_j \in S$, therefore $A u_j = \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} u_i$ for some scalars
$t_{ij}$.  If $T$ is the matrix whose columns are $u_1, \ldots, u_n$, and $R$ the matrix with entries $c_{ij}$,
that says  $A T = T R$.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I tried to edit your comment because t_ij is a typo and you actually meant to use c_ij as scalars.